# Getting GD2 to work on Windows 2000 SP4 (PHP 5.1.6)

Tags: php, windows-server-2000, gd2

I have tried everything.. GD will not enable! Essentially, I have

```
extension_dir="C:\PHP\ext"
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

I've added `c:\php\ext` and `c:\php` to my windows path variable. I copied `php_gd2.dll` to my `system32` folder.. I've scanned my entire INI file to see if there was any other reference to the extension_dir, or GD2.dll extension line, and nothing... GD Still will not enable.

**UPDATE**

I changed the `php.ini` files in my `C:\PHP` folder as well as my `C:\WINNT` folders - actually they both show that GD should be enabled - I also upped the memory from `8M` to `32M` in both files and no luck, still.

**UPDATE 2**

We are moving the darn thing to a different server. It's not worth all of the time trying to get this darn thing working. Thanks to all that contributed.

[phpinfo() Link (http://netcomdevelopment.com/test.php)](http://www.netcomdevelopment.com/test.php)

[image: EXT directory File Listing]

Comment: Where did you get the DLL? The one bundled with PHP 5.1.6? You might want to put `display_startup_errors` to On and see if there's an error message. This might be a version problem.

Comment: It was the original bundled with PHP 5.1.6. No startup errors....

Comment: Correction - no startup errors, but I do get a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg() in C:\www\netcom\getProjectImage.php on line 18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem once upon a time.  IIRC PHP was not using the php.INI file I thought it was using, so all my edits had no effect.

Oh!  I even [blogged about another difficulty](http://n8v.enteuxis.org/2008/11/getting-phps-gd-module-to-work-with-iis/) I had with GD on Windows, after I convinced it to find the GD2 DLL in the first place.  That was on Windows 2003 but I think it applies even more in 2000land.

Comment: How can I check if my PHP file is being used? `I work with PHP on a bunch of different web servers. In this case I needed to resize photos (JPEGs) from Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL) blobs on a Windows web server running IIS.` That's exactly what I'm doing - but I've already extracted the images to files in an attempt to shrink the DB

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the `php.ini` files in my `C:\PHP` folder as well as my `C:\WINNT` folders - actually they both show that GD should be enabled - I also upped the memory from `8M` to `32M` in both files and no luck, still.

Comment: So, empirically, you could make insane changes to your PHP.ini and they should do something, right?  Also, try searching for files named php.ini.  You should also be able to see which ini file is in effect by looking at the output of `php_info()`, but it can be confusing.

Comment: The php_info() on my server I wrote about says "Configuration File (php.ini) Path - C:\WINDOWS" and "Loaded Configuration File - C:\php\php.ini"  Somehow I think I had to make an environment variable or something to et it in the right place.  Also, did you copy the GD DLL to your %SYSTEM% dir?  It's stupid but it was necessary for me.

Comment: Oh, I see your php_info and stuff.  How about permissions?  It is loading other dll extensions, right?  Can you upgrade to a newer PHP?  That solved a problem like this for me at one point.

Comment: We are moving the darn thing to a different server. It's not worth all of the time trying to get this darn thing working. Thanks for trying, Nathan!

Comment: Good call.  Microsoft's Web Platform Installer has made PHP much less painful on IIS.